# Android drawable: different densities or scale

Tags: android, assets

I have designed an in-app keypad for my Android application and I need to provide an image for every key. Currently I've only loaded one large image for each one that is being scaled down to adjust to the layout. Also, this looks nice in every resolution.

Is this approach acceptable or should I provide different images for different screen densities? Currently I've placed those inside the generic drawable directory.

Comment: If you place files in the drawable directory then please do not speak about assets as the assets directory is something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should. Some mobiles with lower resolution, usually won't have much memory. Loading large images in small screen takes too much memory, which might end up crashing. So if you give different images, then according to density it will take appropriate images. check [this](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) out.

Answer (score 2):

It's acceptable in some cases but certainly not optimal.

For best memory performance and the least amount of artifacts I would still recommend to provide alternative bitmap resources for different densities, like the Android documentation recommends.